# Testlink- SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: testlink

I'm the Admin user in Testlink. I'm trying to Reset the password of an user. when clicking on Reset Password button the following message appearing.
**Password Reset can not be done. Reason: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.** Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

```
/* [SMTP] */

/**
 * @var string SMTP server name or IP address ("localhost" should work in the most cases)
 * Configure using custom_config.inc.php
 * @uses lib/functions/email_api.php
 */
 **$g_smtp_host        = '22';  # SMTP server MUST BE configured**

 # Configure using custom_config.inc.php
 $g_tl_admin_email     = 'amirdjn@gmail.com'; # for problem/error notification
 $g_from_email         = 'OAI-Tools@oneaccess-net.com';  # email sender
 $g_return_path_email  = 'amirdjn@gmail.com';
```

Comment: SMTP works on your gmail?

Comment: No it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to SMTP host because

> SMTP server MUST BE configured**

Just set *$g_smtp_host* in your config file:

```
/* [SMTP] */

/**
 * @var string SMTP server name or IP address ("localhost" should work in the most cases)
 * Configure using custom_config.inc.php
 * @uses lib/functions/email_api.php
 */
 # SMTP server MUST BE configured**
 $g_smtp_host        = 'smtp_host_fqdn';

 # Configure using custom_config.inc.php
 $g_tl_admin_email     = 'amirdjn@gmail.com'; # for problem/error notification
 $g_from_email         = 'OAI-Tools@oneaccess-net.com';  # email sender
 $g_return_path_email  = 'amirdjn@gmail.com';
```

Comment: I updated as you mentioned in config.ini.php. But **Password Reset can not be done. Reason: SMTP Hostname seems to be invalid** message displaying.

Comment: Double check your SMTP server hostname is valid: Does `dig $g_smtp_host` resolve the SMTP server IP address?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$g_smtp_host' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink-1.9.14\config.inc.php on line 247

Comment: Could you paste the C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink-1.9.14\config.inc.php line 247?, it looks like **$g_smtp_host** variable has not been properly set.